# cv2 - multi-user image display

Tags: python, opencv, multi-user

Using python and OpenCV, is it possible to display the same image on multiple users?

I am using cv2.imshow but it only displays the image for the user that runs the code.

Thanks

Comment: you would have to create client-server program or stream it on network.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I didn't explain myself properly, the user I want to display the image on is within the same computer. I am able to save photos in their directory so I thought there might be an easier way of displaying an image too. (sorry I'm quite a novice in this and a non native speaker :) )

Answer (score 0):

I was able to display the images on another user/host by setting the DISPLAY environment variable of the X server to match the desired user's DISPLAY.